# What currency is the salary calculator displaying?

Tags: support, salary-calculator

I just did a quick search in my field and was left with a beautiful graph that I don't understand.

```
  Annual Salary | frontend developer | sweden |
  13 years experience | less than a bachelors

  410,000 | 25TH PERCENTILE
  519,000 | 50TH PERCENTILE
  656,000 | 75TH PERCENTILE
```

So is that yearly salary in Swedish Krona (SEK) or US Dollars or Euros?

Comment: Hmm, you would have your personal assistant ask this question if it were dollars or euros.

Comment: @HansPassant haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of those options, I'd choose SEK. Google says the exchange rate is 0.11 USD/SEK. USD 57k (SEK 519k) is a plausible 50th percentile salary for a developer. USD 519,000 is not.

Comment: Would be nice if there was a currency symbol to confirm that. For now it's not an issue but if Denmark and Norway was in, there would be 3 currencies in Kroner/Krona with roughly the same value.

Comment: hey guys, can you tell me what that `Percentile` thing means in salary calculator ?

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz it means that if you look at the 25% of all salaries the _mean_ is 410,000 SEK. If you look at 75% of all salaries then the _mean_ is 656,000 SEK. I put _mean_ in cursive because there is no hard rule on how to calculate the **Percentile**.

Why SO choose to show **Percentile** of ascending salaries, I do not know. I would think that descending order is more useful, so you could see what the top 25% get in salary. Instead you get what the lowest paid 25% get on average etc.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile